# xBee communication problem

Tags: rf, xbee

I'm having a problem using two xbees communicating over a kilometers that I can't solve.

Three weeks ago we checked that these two xbees communicated correctly using two xbee explorers. But last week when we went to install the sensors and boards communication only went from coordinator to router, but not in the other direction, the only difference in these two weeks has been a slight growth from the surrounding vineyard.

My question is:
why would i get 1 way communication only? I'm using same antennas and xbees on both points.

Comment: Links are not always symmetrical - though we often model them as if they were.  However, before you embark on an emag propagation study, have you been able to validate that both are putting out the same amount of power and that for clear LOS you measure the same (i.e. no broken antenna or other simple stuff)?

Comment: In a professional environment, it is expected to regularly monitor and record the signal power status. If I remember correctly, Xbee modules from Digi has that feature.

Comment: @andre_teprom do you mean this?(http://docs.digi.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2626044)